# Add attribute to a row in an array after getting an ID

Tags: javascript, angular

After a modification, I would like to add an attribute to highlight the newest or last updated row in my array until the user leaves the page. I don't know how to select the right row the `getElementsByTagName()` function.

**Component**

Here I get my selected object and add an attribute but the problem is that the id isn't the index of the row so it doesn't add the attribute to the right row.

```
 getById(id: number) {
    this.getByIdSub = this.service.get(id).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (id != null) {
       var t = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[id].setAttribute("id", "test");
      }
    });
  }
```

For example I want to select the first row of my array with the ID 10 and set the attribute to it but it will select the 10th row because I pass the ID 10 in the index.
[my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suAKy.png)
In this picture I clicked on the 3rd row but the first row is highlighted

Comment: Use document.querySelector(`#${id}`).setAttribute("id", "test")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your id is id of the target element, then you can use `document.querySelector("tr#" + id)`. This will select and return TR element with id attribute `id`. So your code would be:

```
 getById(id: number) {
    this.getByIdSub = this.service.get(id).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (id != null) {
       var t = document.querySelector("tr#" + id).setAttribute("id", "test");
      }
    });
  }
```

You can find more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector